# Speeding up repetitive typing

Tags: copy-paste

If I am writing a document say,

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
y = some long equation
\end{equation


\end{document}
```

and some really long equation is needed throughout the whole document (suppose its very important) is there a way of not having to write it out in full every time?

Perhaps some form of copy and pasting (still would rather not have to constantly find the equation in my document and paste it in every time) where I can save the value or something.

Would love the most fastest and easiest approach to this.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you name `(1)` to that long equation and referring it as `(1)` in the rest of the document?

Comment: If it is exactly the same, why not refer to it with `\ref{}` (and `\label{}` inside `equation`).

Comment: P.S. Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Comment: `\newcommand{\mylongequation}{y = \sin (x)}` ?

Comment: I have set up a `glossaries` frame work for my worksheets/problems book and `beamer` slides for equations and formulas that occur very often such that I don't have to type the whole equation each time and - in addition - get consistent naming of variables.

Comment: Please note that `\documentclass[article]` will not work. Use `\documentclass{article}`.